# how to use a processing library in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

I am trying to play an audio file in a java program I have written in Eclipse. Processing has a very good library for playing audio files which I would like to use in Eclipse. I have followed and completed the directions in this link:
https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/ to be able to write Processing java code in Eclipse. I am unclear how one goes about downloading and using Processing libraries in Eclipse. All ideas and links explaining how to download and use this java library: https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/index.html in Eclipse would be much appreciated! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You'd follow pretty much the same steps- add the library jar(s) to your classpath, and then use the classes in those jars.

For example, if you want to use the Processing library [minim](http://code.compartmental.net/tools/minim/), you would simply download [the zip file](http://code.compartmental.net/minim/distro/minim-2.2.0.zip), and then extract the jars within to whatever directory you want. Then you'd right-click your project in eclipse, go to properties, then Java build path. Go to the libraries tab, then just select the minim jar(s) to add them to your classpath.

Then you can use the minim classes just like you can use any other Java library.